# How do i define 'complex rational function'?

Tags: complex-analysis, definition, rational-functions

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_function

I don't get the definition in wikipedia.

It would be great to define "complex rational function" with the domain $\overline{\mathbb{C}}$, namely extended complex plane. So that $\frac{0}{\infty}=0$, $\frac{\infty}{0}=\infty$ and such of these forms are well defined except $\frac{0}{0}$ and $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$

Here's what i figured out to be a right definition:

> =My guess for the definition of **complex rational function**=
>
> Let $\mathbb{C}[X]$ be the ring of complex polynomials.
>
> Define $G=\{(F(X),G(X))\in \mathbb{C}[X]\times \mathbb{C}[X]\setminus\{0\}: \text { $F(X),G(X)$ are relatively prime } \}$
>
> Let $(F(X),G(X))\in G$
>
> Define $r(z)=\frac{F(z)}{G(z)}, \forall z\in\overline{\mathbb{C}}$
>
> Then, $r:\overline{\mathbb{C}}\rightarrow \overline{\mathbb{C}}$ is said to be a rational function.

I think this is what wikipedia describes but since $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ is not defined, $r$ may not be defined.

Is there any way to resolve this? Or if this is not the right definition, what it would be?

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is. We define rational functions the same as over any field, a quotient of polynomials, where the denominator isn't $0$. We can view them also as meromorphic functions, then a rational function is a meromorphic function on the entire Riemann sphere, or as holomorphic mappings, then a rational function is a holomorphic mapping $\overline{\mathbb{C}} \to \overline{\mathbb{C}}$ which isn't $\equiv \infty$ (and the special treatment of $\infty$ here indicates that viewing them as meromorphic functions is a little nicer).

Comment: @Daniel As you said, one can define rational functions the same over *any field*. The problem is $\overline{\mathbb{C}}$ is **not** a field, and it's written in wikipedia that "the complex rational functions are usually defined with the domain $\overline{\mathbb{C}}$. Under the usual construction of the field of rational functions, consider $F(X)=\frac{X+1}{X+2}$. Here, $F(\infty)$ is not well defined. My question:What is the definition of complex rational function whose domain is $\overline{\mathbb{C}}$?

Comment: A meromorphic function on $\overline{\mathbb{C}}$, probably. That makes it clear the collection of all rational functions is a field, so if you're not sticking to "a quotient of polynomials", that seems the best to me.

Comment: @Daniel I found this in wikipedia "one can prove that any meromorphic function on the sphere is rational", but i'm a newbie to complex analysis.. I don't even understand what meromorphic precisely means. Is there any other definition for a complex rational function whose domain is $\overline{\mathbb{C}}$..?

Answer (score 1):

$\infty$ is not really a first-class arithmetic citizen in this case.

What one usually does is to consider $r(z)=\infty$ the encoding of "$r$ has a pole at $z$".

When doing arithmetic on rational functions such as $r/s$ you have a choice between

1. Do it symbolically, following the usual fraction rules, and canceling common factors.
2. Do pointwise arithmetic on all points where the operands are both finite (and, in the case of a denominator, nonzero). There will be finitely many such points because a nonzero polynomial has only finintely many roots. Afterwards fill in the value of any removable singularities.

The function determined by the symbolic result of (1) is the same as the one that results from (2).

---

Your definition of $G$ is slightly off. Usually you would require that $F$ and $G$ are coprime *and* $G$ is monic -- otherwise there will be many representations of the same function that differ by a common factor above and below the fraction bar.

Alternatively start with $\mathbb C[X]\times(\mathbb C[X]\setminus\{0\})$ and quotient out the relation
$$ F/G \sim F'/G' \iff FG'=F'G $$
This is how a field of fractions is defined abstractly, because it doesn't depend on having a canonical choice of representative such as "take the monic one" that needs to look "inside" the structure of the ring elements.

Comment: I know how to construct the field of rational polynomials, and why do one has to care about a representation of *rational polynomial* in this context while one interests in *rational function*?

Comment: @Number9: If you want to have a single representation of each rational function, you need to care that $\frac{x^5+2x^3+1}{3x^{29}+18}$ and $\frac{2x^5+4x^3+2}{6x^{29}+36}$ are the same function. You may not in fact care about that, but if so why do you bother to specify that $F$ and $G$ need to be coprime?

Answer (score 1):

Both the arguments and the values of these rational functions should be viewed as being in $\mathbb C\cup\{\infty\}$.  At points where the denominator is $0$ and the numerator is a non-zero complex number or $\infty$, the value of the function is $\infty$.  Where the argument to the function is $\infty$, the value of the function is a limit as $z$ approaches $\infty$.  This is either some finite complex number or $\infty$. With some functions, like $e^z$, there is no well defined value at $\infty$ in this sense, but with *rational* functions, there always is.  The expressions $0/0$ and $\infty/\infty$ don't arise with *rational* functions except when there is a well defined limit that is either a complex number or $\infty$.

Comment: I'm surprised no one pointed out the glaring error that I just fixed.  With the forms $0/0$ and $\infty/\infty$, the limit need not be either $0$ or $\infty$; rather it is either some complex number or $\infty$.